# Unable to display a new fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, onclick, onclicklistener

I am trying to display a new fragment in Android when a user taps on an item in a ListView. Here is my code for doing so:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            DetailFragment df = new DetailFragment();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Clicked with R.id.list=" + R.id.list, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    

            ft.replace( R.layout.fragment_favorites, df, "DetailFragment" ).addToBackStack(null).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit();
        }
```

When I run this code and tap on an item in the list view, I get the exception:

```
10-09 22:39:05.336: E/AndroidRuntime(25157): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030029 (com.example.proj1:layout/fragment_favorites) for fragment DetailFragment{42430970 #3 id=0x7f030029 DetailFragment}
```

Comment: Replace R.layout.fragment_favorites with the id of your fragment container, ft.replace(R.id.frag_container)

Comment: Your R.java might be corrupt. That might be why the view id cannot be found. Try to clean build your project(In Eclipse, go to Project -> Clean ) and then run it.

Comment: add your activity layout file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Law Gimenez. I am still having issues getting the view to display (I've updated the original post with the logic for this code). Do you have any further suggestions for this?

Comment: Did you changed ID as mentioned by Law Gimenz within `onItemClickListener`.

Comment: @SathishKumar: Yes, I did. That part of the code is now working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

ft.replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container.
containerViewId is Identifier of the container whose fragment(s) are to be replaced. It is not layout.

Check in your activity layout xml, to find the id of the fragment

replace

ft.replace( R.layout.fragment_favorites, df, "DetailFragment" ).addToBackStack(null).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit();

with

ft.replace("Your fragment id", df, "DetailFragment").commit();